# Symfony: Controller type hinting UserInterface

Tags: php, symfony, type-hinting

I really like the feature to insert the current user as an argument in a Controller method. However there is one thing I am not sure about. If I insert the current user in a Controller action like this:

```
public function myAction(UserInterface $currUsr)
{
    $id = $currUsr->getId();
    $email = $currUsr->getEmail();
}
```

I can't know that the object `$currUsr` actually has the methods `getId()` and `getEmail()` because the `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface` does not have these methods defined off course.

What is the point of type hinting then..?

Comment: The point of type hinting is that SF injects the user without you having to retrieve it. A reason why you can’t use a subclass of the core `UserInterface` is mentioned by Stof in comment #6 here: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-user-value-resolver-for-controllers#comment-20618

Comment: Thank you. The link contains some useful information. I guess the docblock can provide the solution for PhpStorm autocompletion and I suppose I can't expect Java-like type strictness from PHP.

Comment: Sure you can: `if (!($user instanceof SiteUserInterface)) throw new Exception(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Since [Symfony 5.2](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-2-controller-argument-attributes) with PHP 8+, you can type hint your argument with the correct type of your user object and apply the #[CurrentUser] attribute to the parameter.

```
public function myAction(#[CurrentUser] ApplicationUser $currUsr)
{
    $id = $currUsr->getId();
    $email = $currUsr->getEmail();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you need more specific class, that has those methods that `UserInterface` is missing, you should use it

```
public function myAction(UserWithMethods $currUsr)
{
    $id = $currUsr->getId();
    $email = $currUsr->getEmail();
}
```

No need to add docblock then.